# Attendance Application Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript

What is this, what does it mean and why am I seeing this? I am making an attendance application and when I live preview this I see Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { .

```
function save() {
var first = document.getElementById('sFirstName');
var last = document.getElementById('sLastName');
var numb = document.getElementById('sNumber');
var pts = document.getElementById('pnts');
}
```

it only seems to appear on the line below.

```
 var studentInfo{
```

but not on this line

```
first: document.getElementById('sFirstName').value,
last: document.getElementById('sLastName').value,
numb: document.getElementById('sNmber').value,
pnts: document.getElementById('pts').value
}
var newobj = [studentInfo];
        localStorage.setItem("student", JSON.stringify(studentInfo));
newobj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("student"));
/*localStorage.setItem("studentInfo", JSON.stringify(studentInfo[index].value;
index = index + 0;
}*/
for(var index =0; index<studentInfo.length;index++){
row = table.insertRow(index+1);
                    cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                    cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                    cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                    cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                    cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
                    cell7 = row.insertCell(6);

    cell1.innerHTML = studentInfo[index].firstName + studentInfo[index].lastName
    cell2.innerHTML = studentInfo[index].studentNumber;
    cell3.innerHTML = studentInfo[index].pnts;
}



function userName() { //this function takes values from the text box and stores them in objects

    var studentInfo = {
        studentNumber: document.getElementById("newUser").value + index,
        lastName: document.getElementById("newlName").value + index,
        firstName: document.getElementById("newfName").value + index

    }; 
}
```

the code is in order from how I have it written.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax should be

```
var studentInfo = {...
               ^^^^
```

You are missing the *assignment operator*.

Answer (score 0):

"the code is in order from how I have it written." No, it is not.

```
var studentInfo{
```

Is indeed wrong

```
var studentInfo = {};
```

Should make you life earier